# How to update source map file (css.map) from css and min.css files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, visual-studio-2019, source-maps

In Visual Studio 2019, is there any easy tool to update source map file (css.map) from a css and min.css files?

I have a default.less file in a project which contains a default.css and then nested to it two files: default.css.map and default.min.css

```
+ default.less
     |
     |-----+ default.css
               |
               |-----+ default.css.map
               |
               |-----+ default.min.css
```

I have never worked with less. This project was build by other people. It seems there is installed a nuget package called dotless in the project. I am completely new in this project assigned, I have to maintain it.

When asp.net mvc app is executed I get an error which says it cannot parse content for default.css.map file. It seems default.css.map file is not correctly updated from default.css and default.min.css.

So now I am trying to update default.css.map file from default.css and default.min.css. I have no idea on how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have always found using explicit `.map` files annoying. Near all LESS compilers come with an option to compile the map source into the `.css` file. This is the best option as it is always up to date and then you can just make a prod config that does not include the map.

I mostly use WebCompiler in my mvc apps, although webpack also has this functionality.